# Haskell list of functions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have many functions (no arguments ) like below and all return a Bool

```
 t0 = 2 == (1+1)

 t1 = "" == []
```

And all the way up to t99

Can I create a list with all these function results. An example is below but I have to type it all out...

```
 tests = [t0,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5 ........... t99]
```

Can I do something with list comprehension to avoid typing that all out ??

Thanks

Comment: These are not functions, they are `Bool`s. There is no such thing as a function with no arguments. And how did you end up with values `t1` through `t99` anyway, if not by typing them out by hand? Having 99 named, related variables is very strange indeed, and there is no particularly elegant way to work with them.

Comment: right. thank you for that. i am new to haskell sorry

Comment: What problem would this solve for you? What are you trying to do? I ask because this is an odd thing to want to do in Haskell and there may be a better way to do whatever you're *really* trying to do.

Comment: You could always just write a program that prints what you want, and then copy-paste it into your source code. Repetitive typing is for people who don't know how to program.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs IT IS A series of test cases for other functions eg `t1 = mymaximum 1 2 == 2`
so i want to check if my test cases work or not

Comment: @JHoe then when you'll understand the basics of the language, you can have a look at Quickcheck. It might help you to generate test cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If instead of `t0` through `t99`, you write

```
t 0 = 2 == 1+1
t 1 = "" == []
-- ...
t 99 = 'a' == pred 'b'
```

then you can use `map t [0..99]` to apply `t` to the numbers `0` through `99`.